# How to change PO delivery date via ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST?

Tags: abap, purchase-order, badi

I need to update the delivery date of the purchase order.

I used the `ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST` BAdI in the `POST` method but it does not update the dates in the `EKET` table, only the dates on the screen are updated.

Here is the code in the method `POST`:

```
 CALL METHOD im_header->get_data
   RECEIVING
     re_data = ls_header_data.

  lt_items = im_header->get_items( ).


  LOOP AT lt_items INTO ls_items.

    lo_item = ls_items-item.
    ls_dati = lo_item->get_data( ).
    lt_schedule = lo_item->get_schedules( ).


    LOOP AT lt_schedule INTO ls_schedule.

      lo_schedule = ls_schedule-schedule.
      ls_meposchedule = lo_schedule->get_data( ).

      IF lv_data GE ls_meposchedule_pai-eindt.
        ls_meposchedule-eindt = lv_data.
      ENDIF.

      lo_schedule->set_data( ls_meposchedule ).

    ENDLOOP.

  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: I also call lo_schedule->set_data( ls_meposchedule ).

Comment: I edited your question to include "set_data" according to your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FUNCTION EXIT_SAPMM06E_017 is used for EKET update.

U need to update (SAPLMEPO)ETT[] table, because you can find changes of PO there.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I used the structure
ASSIGN ('(SAPLEINB) ETS []') TO <fs_data_ets>
does not work.
I was also inspired by this link
https://answers.sap.com/questions/292917/how-to-change-delivery-date-when-save-the-po-1.html
can you help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
METHOD if_ex_me_process_po_cust~process_schedule.

  DATA: lv_eindt TYPE eket-eindt VALUE '20190731'.

  DATA(ls_schedule)  = im_schedule->get_data( ).
  DATA(lr_item)      = im_schedule->get_item( ).
  DATA(ls_item)      = lr_item->get_data( ).

  ls_item-eindt = lv_eindt.
  lr_item->set_data( ls_item ).

ENDMETHOD.
```

and put it into method `IF_EX_ME_PROCESS_PO_CUST~PROCESS_SCHEDULE`.